# Running a Constant Amount of Asynchronous Tasks At the Same Time Using the Python Asyncio Library

Tags: python, url, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a program where I need to make a large number of URL requests. I cannot make all requests at the same time because there are always new URLs being added to the queue. Neither can I run them synchronously because some requests take a very long time to finish which would slow down the program. What I think would be best is to make sure a specific number of asynchronous tasks are running at the same time by launching new tasks whenever a task is completed.

The problem is that I have not found any other way to use the asyncio library other than to make a large array of tasks and await them. This is problematic because there is always a couple of requests getting stuck which causes the program to get stuck at await.

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could either use asyncio.wait_for() or you could use this https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout